# Что значит void main() => runApp(new MyApp()) во flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, кроссплатформенность

Вопрос был в топике выше.У меня вопрос только к знаку "=>",все остальное я понял.Если я правильно понял,то этот знак "=>" значит сокращение

```
void main() {
    this.runApp(new MyApp())
}
```

Или так называемое "тело функции".

Answer (score 3):

`=> expr` это синтаксический сахар и обозначает сокращенное `{ return expr; }`

Почитайте [здесь](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)  про Dart

Comment: Не стал бы называть это "синтаксический сахар", так как это пришло из функционального программирования. Прочитайте про чистые функции.

Comment: @MiT да хоть откуда бы не пришло. Пусть даже с луны свалилось) Это сахарок) Читаем определение: `Синтаксический сахар - это синтаксические возможности, применение которых не влияет на поведение программы, но делает использование языка более удобным для человека.` Это `=> expr` удобнее чем это `{ return expr; }`? Конечно же да. Удовлетворяет определению? Тоже да.

Comment: ну вот пример опровержения ваших слов: `String text(String t) { print(t); return 'name:' + t; }` запишите этот код с применением "синтаксического сахара", без влияния на поведение программы, то-есть без изменения исходного функционала.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто сокращение возвращаемого значения функции.
Например, одну и туже функцию можно написать двумя способами.

```
String name() {
 return 'My name is Vadim';
}
```

или

```
String name() => 'My name is Vadim';
```